# Ansible is always asking for ssh keyphrase even after adding to ssh-add

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have added my key to `ssh-add` after initialising `$(ssh-agent)`

Raw ssh command works totally fine with just key and no passphrase
`ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@someip`

So far so good, the problem is that in same terminal running if i run ansible playbook, it is asking for key passphrase !!!
and not allowing to automate it

```
TASK [deploy-all : Copy something to remote host] *******************
Wednesday 30 June 2021  18:04:56 +0200 (0:00:00.609)       0:00:03.063 ******** 
Enter passphrase for key 'key.pem':
```

It even asks for the passphrase multiple times... during same playbook execution.
(I have some tasks delegated to localhost delegate_to: "{{ delegate_build_to_host }}", so when context switches to remote host seems to ask passphrase again)

inventory file:

```
[webserver]
dockerall ansible_host=some.host.ip.xy ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=key.pem
```

Playbook is just using the only hostgroup webserver

```
---

- hosts: webserver
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  environment:
    CI: "true"
  vars:
    working_user: root

  - { role: deploy, tags: 'deploy' }
```

First task of deploy role is very simple, and i get asked for passphrase:
`roles/deploy/tasks/main.yaml`

```
# identation is wrong but doesn't matter just copied for example
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/docker/"
    dest: "{{ dc_path }}"
    mode: preserve

// more tasks here some delegated to localhost
- name: "create tmp build directory in build host to contain all sort of tmp files that can be deleted after execution"
  delegate_to: "localhost"
  file:
    path: "{{ tmp_build_path }}"
    recurse: yes
    state: directory

// again after this comment, copy tasks for remote host
```

Key file permissions:

```
stat -c "%a %n" key.pem

600 key.pem
```

Comment: 1) have you tried to pass key using `--private-key` command line option ? 2) are you encountering the issue for `webserver` host group ?

Comment: Yes correct i am encouring the issue for webserver host group, the only host group i have with only 1 host. How can i pass the key with --private-key please ellaborate more i don't have that knowledge

Comment: playbook just uses webserver host group `- hosts: webserver
  become: true... more stuff`

Comment: `--private-key key.pem`  while running the playbook

Comment: also, post your task. You may redact non-essential stuff

Comment: I have a lot of tasks and roles, but not sure how that is related will post it though. There are just copy modue calls, script

Comment: I tested ansible-playbook with --private-key key.pem and same result got asked for passphrase several times

Comment: fine, so `deploy-all : Copy something to remote host` is the first task in your playbook ?

Comment: no is not that, i posted the playbook now. The first task that i get asked for passphrase and that get executed for remote webserver host is `  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/docker/"
    dest: "{{ dc_path }}"
    mode: preserve`

Comment: updated question added more detailed role content including tasks

Comment: also, while setting up passwordless access have you done `ssh-agent bash && ssh-add key.pem` ?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html#setting-up-ssh-keys

Comment: @P.... yes I did exactly that as mentioned in question. And for ssh command works fine, I don't get asked for passphrase. Ansible still asks me passphrase

Comment: something is different with your key, could not reproduce the issue in my env, check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once where people reported similar issues

Comment: @P.... thanks, i tried that too was similar to what you suggested and i tried already ssh-agent then add key with ssh-key and did not work. Is really weird..

Answer (score 2):

Setting `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=key.pem` will overwrite your ssh-agent config and ansible will ask your ssh password for each host (cause it don't look anymore on ssh-agent parameters and base itself on just ansible config).

Delete the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` from your ansible file and add a config block in your `~/home/.ssh.config` for your servers (example below)

```
Host test
  HostName 192.168.5.30
  Port 22
  User <ssh user to connect>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your ssh private key>
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Like so you keep all your ssh config to `ssh-agent`

Hope that this answer will still help some people after 1 year